# Check value of next line without moving streamreaders pointer

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader, peek

I got a .csv file which looks like this:

[image: csv file]

I am using C# Streamreader to read every line.

I want to do following:
When my Streamreader is at the first line I want to check the value of the second line without moving my Streamreaders pointer to the second line.

I am looking for something like Streamreader.Peek()

But Peek() only checks if there's ANYTHING in the next line or not.
I want to check the value of the next line and decide what to do (without moving the Streamreaders pointer).

Comment: That definitely sounds like an XY problem. What is it that you're actually trying to do? In order to read the data of the next line, you have to advance the reader to the next line, it's as simple as that. Why don't you want to advance the reader? Do you want to rewind it instead? Or don't you rather want to save the current line in memory and then read the next?

Comment: It reads a stream.  The nature of streams is that they come by and never come by again.  If you want to read and process things one line ahead, create a variable called `lastLine` and keep track of the current and last line.

Comment: Is reading all lines into an array and then parsing that array a viable option?

Answer (score -1):

You can make new stream based on decorator pattern (for one line buffer)